# Download file on a specific location - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to convert a canvas to image. The code used is as follows.

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
url = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
window.open(url);
```

The above code saves the image on the downloads folder.  I need to save the image on a specific folder(Eg: /home/username/Desktop/projects/MyProject1/images/).

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: Not at all; the decision where to save downloads is the user’s to make. You can not force it (at least not with JavaScript running in the context of a website.)

Comment: Maybe you have to change some options in your browser.

Comment: If this is for your personal use, try looking in the settings of your browser and change the Default download destination.